# Looking for a better layout or style in writing solutions of equations

Tags: code-review

Before I proceed to write a lot of solutions, I want to adopt a style that I will use consistently in my document. So far I write a solution of an equation as follows. Could you review  this ? Any comment, suggestions, improvements to make mine better, more readable, etc are always welcome.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Solve $-5(1 - 7 x) (3 x + 10) (2 x + 1)=0$ with  factorization.
\begin{gather*}
-5(1 - 7 x) (3 x + 10) (2 x + 1)=0\\
1-7x =0     \qquad \text{or}\qquad  3x+10 = 0 \qquad \text{or}\qquad 2x+1=0 \\ 
-7x =-1     \qquad \text{or}\qquad  3x = -10  \qquad \text{or}\qquad 2x=-1 \\
\begin{aligned}[t]
x &= \frac{-1}{-7}\\
  &= \frac{1}{7}
\end{aligned}  \qquad \text{or}\qquad  
\begin{aligned}[t]
x &= \frac{-10}{3}\\
  &= -\frac{10}{3}
\end{aligned} 
  \qquad \text{or}\qquad 
\begin{aligned}[t]
x &= \frac{-1}{2}\\
  &= -\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
Thus the solution is $x\in \{-\frac{10}{3},-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{7}\} $.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like your layout... except the `=` and `or`s are not vertically aligned.  So, why not try `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}` ...instead of `\begin{gather*}` and `\end{gather*}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this look to be a better way to align your equations...

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\nxt}{&          &&}  %%  next column
\newcommand{\nxr}{&\text{or} &&}  %%  next column with "or" 

\begin{document}

Solve $-5(1 - 7 x) (3 x + 10) (2 x + 1)=0$ with  factorization.
%
\begin{align*}
-5(1 - 7 x) (3 x + 10) (2 x + 1) = 0
\end{align*}
%
\begin{align*}
1-7x &=  0            \nxr    3x+10 &=   0           \nxr      2x+1 &=  0 \\ 
 -7x &= -1            \nxr    3x    &= -10           \nxr      2x   &= -1 \\
   x &= \frac{-1}{-7} \nxr     x    &= \frac{-10}{3} \nxr       x   &= \frac{-1}{2} \\
     &= \frac{1}{7}   \nxt          &= -\frac{10}{3} \nxt           &= -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
%
Thus the solution is $x\in \{-\frac{10}{3},-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{7}\} $.

\end{document}
```

Comment: OK. Thank you. Looks more readable!

Comment: Good to know you liked it.